# Median calculation in matlab(image processing)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to find `MajorAxisLength` for each of the connected components using `regionprops`.Then I am calculating `median` for the same.But I am getting wrong value of median.Here is my code-

```
  clc;
image=imread('test3.png');

image = im2bw(image);
image=imcomplement(image);

[imx imy]=size(image);
n1=zeros(imx,imy);
count=1;
connected = bwlabel(image,8) ;
mx=max(max(connected));
for i=1:mx
    [r,c] = find(connected==i);
    test=zeros(imx,imy);
    rc = [r c];
    [sx sy]=size(rc);


    for j=1:sx
        x1=rc(j,1);
        y1=rc(j,2);
        test(x1,y1)=1;
    end
    s(i)=regionprops(test,'MajorAxisLength');
    if(s(i).MajorAxisLength >=5)
       ss(count)=s(i).MajorAxisLength;
       count=count+1;       
    end
end



for k=1:count
    disp(ss(k));
end
M=median(ss)
```

These are the values I get for `ss` array-

```
100.7208    
141.7638
108.0241
102.5751
84.8693
107.9178
97.9122
183.8361
95.8895
102.5912
90.2462
```

And this is the value of median I get(which is definitely wrong)-

```
M =

   25.3651
```

Here is my input image-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because maybe you are running this a second time with a different image than you did the first time.The variable `ss` is already stored in memory and it has  elements of your last run also stored.Say for example with your last test image you got `50` elements in ss,this time you are getting only `25`.Still `ss` is saved in memory and has all `50` elements.So for median calculation all these values are used.You can use this to declare the array-

```
ss = zeros(mx,1);
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Hi! I've made a chatroom for us so we can discuss things related to MATLAB that may be off-topic, or spans longer than what can be placed in a comments box.  Come visit when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab